# Flexible functions | modify any variable with one funciton

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I was just wondering whether or not is it possible to define one function and use it to modify whatever variable you want? I know you can modify the value of a variable with paramteres and arguments, but can you somehow use them to modify different variables each time? Something like this:

```
var x, y;

function foo(parameter1, parameter2) {
    parameter1 = parameter2;
}

foo(x, 'Hello World');
foo(y, 'Bye Bye World');
```

And I am also wondering if you can do this with objects as well, something like:

```
function Object() {
    this.x;
    this.y;
}

function foo(param1, param2) {
    param1 = param2;
}

var object = new Object();
foo(object.x, 'Hello World');
foo(object.y, 'Bye Bye World');
```

Comment: No, that's not possible. JS cannot pass variables by reference.

Comment: oh ok. Thought so. Thanks for the response tho

Comment: You might want to consider using pure functions (for various reasons) - which would also help you define the reusable function your after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. JS cannot pass variables by reference.

> And I am also wondering if you can do this with objects

You can mutate objects that were passed to your function, but again you cannot pass a property by reference. You could pass the object and the property name:

```
function foo(obj, name, value) {
    obj[name] = value;
}

var object = {
  x: '',
  y: '',
};
foo(object, 'x', 'Hello World');
foo(object, 'y', 'Bye Bye World');
```

Comment: Thanks, that at least somehow does what I wanted to do with the object thing, so thank you for that!

Comment: JS is a quite powerful language, and passing closures around will allow you to do almost anything, but it's unclear what your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) is.